# Is my ANOVA Java Code wrong or is the difference because of computer arithmetic?

Tags: anova, java

| Statistics | Text | Phone | App | In person | Overall |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sample Size | 248 | 36 | 67 | 94 | 445 |
| Mean | 99.8 | 109.6 | 40.6 | 46.8 | 80.5 |
| Standard Deviation | 135.7 | 126.2 | 85.6 | 85.6 | 122.0 |

I expected

|  | df | SS | MS | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Groups | 3 | 336655.5 | 112218.5 | 7.889 |
| Error | 441 | 6272849.6 | 14224.1 |  |
| Total | 444 | 6609505.2 |  |  |

My code gives me

```
F is7.883051165927892
overall mean is80.48404494382022
df groups is3
df error is441.0
df total is444.0
SS groups is336282.0967191011
SS Error is6270854.669999999
MS Groups is112094.03223970036
MS Error is14219.625102040814
SS Total is6607136.7667191
```

My data puts the input table in the format

```
None        |Sample Size | Mean| Standard Deviation
Group 1|248.0 99.8 135.7 
Group 2 |36.0 109.6 126.2 
Group 3|67.0 40.6 85.6 
Group 4 |94.0 46.8 85.6
```

My code is

```
    // Online Java Compiler
// Use this editor to write, compile and run your Java code online
import java.lang.Math;
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Try programiz.pro");
        int rows = 4;//number of groups
        int columns = 3;// one for sample size, the second for the means, the third for the standard deviations. always
        double[][] array = new double[rows][columns];
        array[0][0]=248;
        array[0][1]=99.8;
        array[0][2]=135.7;
        array[1][0]=36;
        array[1][1]=109.6;
        array[1][2]=126.2;
        array[2][0]=67;
        array[2][1]=40.6;
        array[2][2]=85.6;
        array[3][0]=94;
        array[3][1]=46.8;
        array[3][2]=85.6;
         for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        
        double SST=0.0;
        double avgMean=0.0;
        double N=0;
        for (int i=0;i<rows;i++)
        {
            N+=array[i][0];
        }
        for (int i=0; i<rows;i++)
        {
                avgMean+=array[i][1]*(array[i][0]/N);
        }
        for (int i=0;i<rows;i++)
        {
            SST+=array[i][0]*Math.pow(array[i][1]-avgMean,2);
        }
        //System.out.println(SST);
        double MST=SST/(rows-1);
        double SSE=0;
        for (int i=0; i<rows;i++)
        {
            SSE+=(array[i][0]-1)*Math.pow(array[i][columns-1],2);
        }
        //System.out.println(SSE);
       
        double MSE=SSE/(N-rows);
        double F=MST/MSE;
        System.out.println("F is" +F);
        System.out.println("overall mean is" + avgMean);
        System.out.println("df groups is" +(rows-1));
        
        System.out.println("df error is" + (N-rows));
        System.out.println("df total is" + (N-1));
        System.out.println("SS groups is" + SST);
        System.out.println("SS Error is"+ SSE);
        System.out.println("MS Groups is" + MST);
        System.out.println("MS Error is"  + MSE);
        System.out.println("SS Total is" + (SST+SSE));
        
    }
}
```

I ran code on https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/online-compiler/.
I inferred the formula for anova on https://byjus.com/anova-formula/.